# where did word "ballistic/ballista" originate from?

Tags: etymology

*Cubic* is the adjective form of the noun *cube*.

Where did the adjective *ballistic* originate? Is *ballistic* the adjective form of *ball*?

The word *ballista* means a catapult. Is this because the launched items were balls? Or there is another reason?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: 'ballista' is rare. Catapult is what it is normally called in English (and some kinds of catapult are called a 'trebuchet')

Comment: @Mitch. Ok. How is that relevant...?

Comment: @Mitch No, trebuchet are not a type of catapult, any more than a shotgun is a type of rifle.

Comment: @cde trebuchet **[are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trebuchet)** a type of catapult, just like a shotgun is a type of firearm

Comment: @only_pro to any body with only passing familiarity with English may take the juxtaposition of ballistics and ballista as being of roughly the same status. I'm just pointing out to them that most English speakers would not even recognize it as a word.

Comment: @Mitch  most English speakers ... who didn't/don't play [age of empires](https://ageofempires.fandom.com/wiki/Ballista_(Age_of_Empires)),   [world of warcraft](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Ballista), [d & d](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Medium_Ballista_(5e_Equipment)) or watch [game of thrones](https://www.popularmechanics.com/culture/tv/a27520/game-of-thrones-ballista/) - though Cersei does call them scorpions. I don't think it's that obscure a term

Comment: @mcalex Wikipedia is your citation. Wow. But no, they are not. They don't even work on the same principle.  And yes, a shotgun is a firearm. It is not a rifle.

Comment: @cde The catapult 'principle' is to hurl objects a great distance: [cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catapult), [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catapult).  Catapults include [slingshots](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slingshot), and [aircraft launchers](https://science.howstuffworks.com/aircraft-carrier3.htm).  [Trebuchets](https://sites.google.com/site/nicolasduronioscatapultproject/home/3-main-types-of-catapults) are a specific type of catapult - as are mangonels and ballista.  (Is it mangonel that you mean when you say catapult?)

Comment: @mcalex: You're inverting the definitions. A catapult is able to hurl objects at a great distance, but that doesn't mean that every object that can hurl objects at a great distance is a catapult.  Look up [cow](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cow): "a large female farm animal kept to produce meat and milk". However, that definition could also apply to other animals such as a goat, and that does not in any way mean that a cow is a goat, or a goat is a cow. Similarly, catapults, trebuchets and ballistae have the same purpose but are distinct types of siege engine.

Comment: @mcalex: To expand the counterexamples: [car](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/car) is defined as "a road vehicle with an engine, four wheels, and seats for a small number of people" but that definition also applies to a quadbike (ATV), even though a quadbike is not a car and a car is not a quadbike (ATV).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [EtymOnline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ballistic#etymonline_v_26876), "ballistic":

> "pertaining to construction and use of thrown objects," ultimately from Greek *ballein* "to throw"

A [ballista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballista) could use stone (ball) projectiles, but also fired bolts like a crossbow. The "ball" in "ballistic" and "ball" as in a round object are only [homonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym) - they sound the same and are spelled the same but ultimately have nothing to do with each other, as "ball" is believed to come from a [Germanic source](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ball#etymonline_v_223).

Answer (score 6):

Given that the plural form of *ballista* is *ballist**ae***, I have a strong felling that the word comes from Latin and is formed this way:

> *ballista* = stem *ball* + suffix *-ista*

And in Latin, stem *ball* comes from Greek and has the meaning of *throwing*, while *-ista* means "one who exercises or practices something" (1st declension, matching the plural nominative of *-istae*). So *ballista* literally means *one who throws*, not any balls.

so the *-ball-* part in *ballista* doesn't really have anything to do with *ball* despite looking simila, as said in Alan T's answer.

Side note: ballistae fire more arrows than stone balls, or i.e. more "long and thin" projectiles than "round and big" objects.

Comment: True, though -ista isn't a native Latin suffix: it comes from Greek -istēs. I don't think it was ever productive in Latin; I've never seen it attached to a native Latin stem, only Greek ones.

Answer (score 4):

In Ancient Greek, *ball-ein* means "to throw". The ending *-ist-ēs* is just like "-ist" in English, meaning someone who does something. So a *ball-ist-ēs* is someone (or in this case something) that throws: it launches wooden or metal bolts, with a mechanism that looks a bit like a crossbow's. In Latin, the *-ēs* ending was replaced with *-a*, giving "ballista".

Similarly, in Ancient Greek, the ending *-ic-os* means "pertaining to". So something that's *ball-ist-ic-os* is "pertaining to throwing things", or acting like something shot out of a ballista.

"Ball" in English is a complete coincidence; it comes from a different Proto-Indo-European root. The cognate of "ball" in Latin is actually *foll-is* "airbag", which much later became English "fool".

Answer (score 3):

The adjective "ballistic" describes the flight of an object through space. It usually applies to projectiles like bullets or rockets that are fired from weapons.

the word comes from weapon "BALLISTA", which chucked rocks into the air,

whose name comes from the Greek for "throw."

If someone has “gone ballistic,” they're crazy with anger. When you go ballistic,
 you’re just like an unmanned missile: you fly into a fit of rage and lose control over your feelings or actions.

https://news.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/news/2017/05/23/scotland_roman/02_Scotland_Roman.adapt.885.1.jpg

Comment: gone ballistic in terms of an anger response is so new I always thought it referred to the launch of nuclear weapons (which are on ballistic e.g. suborbital) missiles.